# GTK GUI freezes with async/await and Progress<T>

Tags: c#, gtk, async-await, gtk#

I'm using GTK# to build a GUI. Some data is processed in the background and I'd like to see some info about the progress on the user interface. Here is some code demonstrating the way I am trying to do this:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    //a button and a textfield
    private VBox VB = new VBox();
    private Button B = new Button("Push dis");
    private Label L = new Label("0");

    public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {

        B.Clicked += OnClickEvent;
        ////////////////////
        VB.PackStart (B);
        VB.PackStart (L);
        Add (VB);
        ShowAll ();
        Build ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    //async method incrementing variable, simulating some work and sending its progress
    protected async Task CounterGUIUpdateAsync(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
         await Task.Run (() => {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
                Thread.Sleep (100);
                if(progress != null)
                {
                    var stri = Convert.ToString(i);
                    progress.Report(stri);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    //event handler for the button
    protected async void OnClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ProgressIndicator = new Progress<string> (ReportProgress);
        await CounterGUIUpdateAsync (ProgressIndicator);
    }

    //action connected to the progress instance 
    protected void ReportProgress(string value)
    {
        L.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Running the code will start off as expected, but at some point it is likely that the displayed counter gets stuck. The GUI won't update anymore, turning black if it has been minimized. It is still functional though.

Help is appreciated very much.

Comment: what version of Gtk# are you using and what OS are you using? in case you're in Windows, are you using Mono or .NET?

Comment: GTK# 2.12 under Windows 7. I'm using Mono/ .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're not using the main thread (the gui thread) when using the Gtk+ API. You need to use Gtk.Application.Invoke() passing a delegate that manipulates the UI, so the action is performed in the correct thread.

You can read more about this [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Responsive_Applications#Gtk.Application.Invoke).

Comment: That seems to be it. I've used Gtk.Application.Invoke(delegate{//dosomeGUIUpdate...}) in the Report method. Thanks!

Comment: As soon as I am allowed to ;)