# GTK Sharp synchronization context doesn't seem to exist, breaking async/await by default

Tags: c#, async-await, gtk#

I am using MonoDevelop with GTK Sharp 2.12. I have set this up using the default GTK Sharp windowed project. Add a button, add a button-click event and placed the following code:

```
protected async void OnBtnTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Before: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    Debug.WriteLine($"After: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

    using (var msg = new MessageDialog(this, DialogFlags.Modal,
        MessageType.Info, ButtonsType.Ok, "CRASH"))
    {
        msg.Run();
        msg.Destroy();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Before: 1
Started Thread 27672
After: 4

(TestSyncContext:26912): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_set_geometry_hints: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
```

The "critical" line is a crash in the program -- This is because the UI thread didn't return when continuing on to show the `MessageDialog`. You can see the managed thread ID changed after the call to `await`.

Puzzled by this, I started researching and [found this bit of code](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/mono_v4.9/arch/amd64_linux26/gtk-sharp/gtk/Application.cs) from a long, long time ago; Specifically these lines caught my attention:

```
gtk_init (ref argc, ref argv);
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext (new GLib.GLibSynchronizationContext ());
```

So I started to wonder: Does GTK Sharp not set up a synchronization context by default?

I decided to throw it in the code, but `GLib.GLibSynchronizationContext()` **does not exist** in the `GLib` library.

OK, that's odd -- I searched for that on the web and found the [source code](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/master/glib/GLibSynchronizationContext.cs) to that object; Copied and pasted it in to my project, then called it as so:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new GLibSynchronizationContext());

        MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
        win.Show();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Ran it again, and it performs how I would have expected it to without adding a context:

```
Before: 1
Started Thread 22744
After: 1
```

No crashes. UI thread came back to continue on down the method.

My questions are:

1. Did GTK Sharp intentionally not include a synchronization context in their UI framework on purpose?
2. Did GTK Sharp intentionally not attempt to initialize a sync-ctx on purpose? Meaning they never intended it to work with the async/await pattern by default?
3. Why is `GLib.GLibSynchronizationContext` no longer available?
4. Is what I did to fix it the correct way to add a proper sync-ctx to GTK Sharp?

I have production code with this fix going out, and I want to make sure that what I did isn't unorthodox. OR: maybe there is a better way to set up GTK Sharp to handle the async/await pattern that isn't very well documented.

Comment: From memory I don't think GTK# plays well with running on any threads other than the main thread. Maybe this is related.

Comment: @muszeo -- it plays great with the async/await pattern, as long as you set up a synchronization context. I just want to know why it's not set up by default.

Comment: GTK# is designed to run on the main (UI) thread, as fas a I know. If you want to invoke UI behaviour from another thread you need to use Gtk.Application.Invoke (delegate) where the delegate manipulates the UI thread. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096088/gtk-gui-freezes-with-async-await-and-progresst

Comment: And to answer you question -- I'm not sure why it's not set up, but given that it isn't, I wouldn't necessarily assume that setting one up would result in predictable behaviour on every occasion. It's worth asking someone at the mono-project if you're really keen to use it.

Comment: I figured I'd post an update: This has been running for a couple months on thousands of machines in a production environment and there have been no issues what-so-ever. I did [cross-post this question](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/issues/293) on the GTK-Sharp github page.